# When does unordered_set invoke operator==?

Tags: c++, hash, hashset, unordered-set

In my thought,

This was how unordered_set insertion was working.

- When insert was called, hash function is called.
- In my code below I hash `first` and `second` value in pair<string, string> each.

  -> `Test(make_pair("good","james"))` ( make Test object )

  -> `return hasher(test.get_name().first) + hasher(test.get_name().second)` ( hash function returns )

  -> `8838398861423961495` ( hash value )
- and It tries to find same hash value in hash table.
- If it fails to find same hash value in hash table, then it make its hash value in hash table.

So, I thought elements with different hash value should not be compared in unordered_set.

And this is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test(pair<string, string> n):name(n){};
    
    pair<string,string> get_name() const { return name; };

    bool operator==(const Test &test) const
    {
        cout << "compare " << get_name().first << ',' << get_name().second << ':' << test.get_name().first << ',' << test.get_name().second << '\n';
        return (name == test.get_name());
    }

private:
    pair<string,string> name;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Test>
    {
        hash<string> hasher;
        size_t operator() (const Test& test) const noexcept
        {
            cout << test.get_name().first << ',' << test.get_name().second << ':' << (hasher(test.get_name().first) + hasher(test.get_name().second)) << '\n';
            return hasher(test.get_name().first) + hasher(test.get_name().second);
        }
    };
}


int main()
{
    unordered_set<Test> hash_set;
    hash_set.insert(Test(make_pair("song","james")));
    hash_set.insert(Test(make_pair("kim","james")));
    hash_set.insert(Test(make_pair("kim","james")));

    cout << hash_set.size() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It tries to insert three Test object in hash_set.

First one and Second one should not have same hash value ( But It can happen in possibility )

And I made `operator==` `cout` whenever its called to look when it is invoked.

Also the `hash` function.

And this is the results.

```
song,james:1897374899324052084
kim,james:6658567258605789090
compare song,james:kim,james
kim,james:6658567258605789090
compare kim,james:kim,james
2
```

How can (song, james) and (kim, james) can be compared ( by calling `==` ) even though they are not in the same bucket ( not same hash value )?

And also, If I change "song" to "good", It changes it result.

( I use Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1) and std=c++14 )

Comment: You normally have >1 possible hash value per bucket. Allocating buckets costs memory, and 2^64 buckets couldn't possibly fit.

Comment: Both gcc/ msvc do only the last comparison [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M7xoEve4G), only libc++ compare both.

Comment: I want to know when does `==` called. Because just changing 'song' to 'good' in first Test object changes its behavior ( not calling `==` ) even though hash values are still different from (kim,james)

Comment: @codeDog You can't know that (unless you are going to analyse your standard library implementation...). The way buckets are handled should not be your concern unless your program doesn't meet speed requirements, you profiled your code and found out that it's specifically the unordered_map that is the bottleneck.

Comment: Print `hash_set.bucket(Test(make_pair("song","james")))` and `hash_set.bucket(Test(make_pair("kim","james")))` (it would be equal when you have "extra" comparison).

Comment: The likelihood of two (seemingly totally different) hashes going in same bucket is 1/hash_set.bucket_count() . So song,james and kim,james can be in same bucket for your compiler but good,james and kim,james not. Other compiler may choose other bucket_count for starters and so give different result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each bucket of the hash table contains many different of your hashes. Otherwise you would need to store 2^64 buckets in memory if your hash is 64bit wide, for which you obviously don't have enough memory.

Or in other words, the `std::unordered_set` implementation will apply its own hash to a smaller range on top of yours (although that can be very trivial such as taking the lowest bits of your hash). The whole point of the hash is to reduce the number of possible input values to a small range, hopefully uniformly distributed.

So even if the hashes calculated by your hash function are different, they may still be put in the same bucket and then it is up to the implementation whether or not it will immediately use `==` to compare the elements belonging to the same bucket, or whether it will try your hash function's output for comparison first.

And even more generally, there is in principle nothing forbidding the implementation to do a `==` comparison unnecessarily, although of course that wouldn't be good for the quality of the implementation.

Comment: Printing `hash_set.bucket(test)` shows that there are in same bucket, and it is not a poor quality of implementation :)

Comment: So Is it okay to think like objects with same hashes are guaranteed to be compared, but objects with different hashes are compared "Random"( not exactly random but depends on compilers or like that?)?

Comment: @codeDog Yes, it will depend on the standard library implementation and the current state of the set (e.g. how many buckets are currently used). You shouldn't make any assumptions about whether or not `==` is called in any specific instance. The best you can do is to make sure that your hash function has a good distribution over your input distribution, also with respect to subsets of bits in the hash, so that there are low number of collisions requiring less calls to `==`